# sql server geometry find points intersection buffer

Tags: sql-server, geometry

[image]

How do I find the point of intersection of buffer?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour]

Comment: I found a solution: two method STDistance() and STIntersection()

Comment: Did you want to post your solution in the "Your Answer Section" below.